# How to consume specific messages from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

We are building an application using Kafka and ELK. We store messages into a Kafka Topic. Logstash then reads from the Topic and indexes 'only specific' records into Elasticsearch. Like if a field has certain value, then index it else don't index it and let it remain in topic. This is the design as of now. But in future, we will need to process those messages from the topic which were NOT indexed into Elasticsearch. Is there a way we can later process only those messages from Kafka which were not indexed into ES? If so, how? Do we need to store them in different topics? Or we can use the same topic and same consumer group but assign them a different partition id while storing in topic.

Can someone please shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep the data in Kafka (ie, topic retention period) you can read the same topic as ofter as you want.

Thus, if you want to process data you did not index in Elasticsearch, you can simple re-read the topic and apply the reverse filter to get all messages that did not end-up in Elasticsearch. For this, I would recommend to use a different consumer group ID.

Of course, you can also write messages that are not loaded into Elasticsearch into a new topic while loading the topic into Elasticsearch (ie, put into Elasticsearch and new topic in a single pass over the date). But than you store the some data twice. Thus, you have a space/time tradeoff for processing non-indexed data later on: if let's say 90% of your data ends-up in Elasticsearch, it might be worth to replicate 10% of you data and speed up processing this data later on (you only need to read the new topic that is 10x smaller). If only 10% of data get's indexed, it seems to be a waste to duplicate 90% of you data, to only save 10% of reading overhead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. 1. What if use a different topic but index ONLY the data that was NOT written into ES into it. I've an if condition for indexing into ES. I can use the else condition to dump into a new topic in Kafka. 2. In case, I use the same topic, How do I apply reverse filter to read from Kafka. 3. The reason I suggested same consumer group is because the [doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers)  states "If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes".

Comment: You have already what I meant by "reverse filter" -> you "else" part that does write data to the topic. But I do not understand why you do write it back into the same topic and not into a new topic? If you write data that you do not index back into the topic you just read, don't you end up in an infinite loop reading all messages that are not indexed over and over again? Or how to you determine when to stop? About consumer groups: it really depend on you overall setup -- if you use a second topic and a new consumer group ID nothing should get read twice.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Yes, I can use Logstash to read from the topic and then use reverse filter to get all the messages that didn't end up in ES. But this will increase processing time. read from kafka input, then grok, split in KV pairs and then finally apply reverse filter on one of the KV pairs. Or did you mean to suggest a different way to consume from kafka like java program? You do have a point when you say that if only 10% records are indexed into ES, then having a different topic would mean 90% data dup though faster processing.

Comment: I don't know the details for logstash -- never used it. But I guess there is some miss understanding going on here. I thought you do have some program that does read the topic and put the data into the index. But now I think that ES read the topic directly and you just pass in some filter function. If this is correct, you can of course no "piggy bag" writing non indexed messages into a new topic -- if you would have a own program as I initially assumed you could to that though.

Comment: No. I do have a program and that's Logstash :). It reads from the topic, does filtering, splitting into KV pairs and then indexes into ES based on the If condition. Thus, I can also index the records matching the else condition into another topic in Logstash.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the range of the offset that have been read and processed with elastic search somewhere (in an external file or in elastic topic itself) and than process data in a second moment just using the specific range interval.

An easy way to read a subset of the Kafka queue delimited by specific offset is by using a spark application with a KafkaRDD: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaRDD.html